# How to test Java 8 in Travis CI?

Tags: java, java-8, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am trying to run a Travis CI test. Like this:

```
language: java
jdk: oraclejdk8
sudo: false
script: mvn test
```

It should be really simple... but I get this erro:

```
 diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
      (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
 lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
```

It was supposed to be Java 8 right? **How can I configure Travis CI to run Java 8 and not Java 5?**

Any help is welcome!

**Edit**

Here is my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>br.com.simplepass</groupId>
  <artifactId>mapPointManager</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>mapPointManager</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
      <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I think your maven pom defines compile targets as java 5 (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

Comment: You should post an answer, so I can accept it

Comment: I'm actually not sure what the answer is / what you changed to make it work. But since you know, you could write your own answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the following tag in your pom script:

```
<build>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</build>
```

This will make your source and target compilation to java 1.8. 
BTW, I have a [GitHub](https://github.com/BitsHammer/jLibrary/) project that uses Java 8 and Travis, you could take a look! Your whole pom would be something like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.simplepass</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapPointManager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>mapPointManager</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Well, this problem was already solved, as I gave my solution 3 days ago hahaha. But thanks for the reply! I'll try your answer and, if it works, I'm gonna accept as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on zapi comment I changed my pom to:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>br.com.simplepass</groupId>
  <artifactId>mapPointManager</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>mapPointManager</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!-- I just added those two lines -->
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
      <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And now Travis is using Java 8.